# Tables join using mapping table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, mapping, outer-join

I have 3 tables:

**table1**: col1(id), col2(segment), col3(sector), col4(year)

***mapping table2***: 
col1(segment1) => values are the same as from table1.col2,
col2(segmnet2) =>values are the same as from table3.col2

**table3**: col1(id), col2(segment), col3(sector), col4(year)

Now, Im doing FULL OUTER JOIN:

```
select t1.id, t3.id
from table1 t1
full outer join table3 t3 on
t1.year = t3.year and....
```

But I also need to join by COL2 - SEGMENT, **with using mapping table**.
How to do correctly do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you just need to add another full outer join:

```
select t1.id, t3.id
from table1 t1
full outer join mapping t2 on( t1.col2= t2.col1)
full outer join table3 t3 on(t1.year = t3.year and t2.col2 = t3.col2
```

Just to make sure - a full outer join keeps all the records from both tables being joined, no matter if there is a match or not! I've added another full outer join but change it to the kind of join you need if it isn't full.

Comment: I know, but I want to display all records from t1 and t3, even sometiems I will get null from t1 or t3

Comment: @user2207426 and whats wrong with the query I gave you?